# MikTeX package manager not installing BibTeX

Tags: packages, miktex, texmaker

I am new to LaTeX and I have installed MikTex distribution and I am using Texmaker. When I compile the simple code shown below I get an error:

```
%_________________Preamble Start___________________________________________
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{scrreprt}

%_________________Encoding_________________________________________________
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

%_________________Referencing__________________________________________
 \usepackage[style=authoryear-comp,natbib]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{References.bib}


\begin{document}

\chapter{Aim of document}
sample text  \citep{hawkins2011owns}?

\end{document}
```

[image]

However, if I use package manager to install the package I get the same error when I recompile. I have Bibtex on my system but Miktex doesn't seem to work with it. How can I specify where to find the .sty file?

Comment: Be careful to run the package manager with the same permissions as you ran the installation.  ie either single user or admin.

Comment: The message is about biblatex not bibtex. Perhaps the installation failed. In the package manager try to synchronize the repository or to change to another one. Try to install also in user mode and not "for everyone" with admin rights.

Comment: Thank you, changing the permissions corrected the error. If you write this up as an answer I can accept it.

Comment: @R.Schumacher ^^^^^^^^

Comment: @R.Schumacher Do you want to answer or take any other action?

Answer (score 2):

When setting up a LaTex installation it is important that you are consistent with the permissions chosen for both the installation and usage of any portion of the setup.  This is especially important for any Windows installation.

1)  If you are going to be the only person using LaTeX on this computer and you do not have access to the admin settings, then you must choose local for all of the installation.  Be aware that if you log in with any other account, then the LaTeX software will not correctly compile.

2)  If you have admin access or you want to have LaTeX available in multiple accounts then you may prefer to use the 'for everyone' option.

Caution:  On any system if you choose the 'for everyone' solution, then you must be very careful to only install 'known safe software' as any thing you do here can effect every account.

GENERAL RECOMMENDATION:  Install LaTeX and associated software in single user mode.  If there are multiple users who also want to use LaTeX on this computer, do their installation also in single user mode.  Then any specific user's customization will not affect the other users.